# Website is not aligned properly on Tablet and Mobile

Tags: css

My website is "www.euromoneyfinancial.com" . I want my website with the width of 1200px and centrally aligned. It is showing properly on my Laptop. But it is aligned on right in tablet and mobile..
Code in body tag is:-

```
body {
font: 12px/20px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:20px;
color:#666565;
position:relative;
width: 1200px;
background: #000;
margin-left:72px;}
```

Can someone suggest the fault in coding or any alternative to achieve the desired layout for my website?

Comment: Actually, you're site is aligned to the left on any device, including desktop. You've just pushed it to the right with `margin-left`. If you actually want to center your website remove `margin-left` and use `margin: 0 auto;`. There's also a lot of other things you could do but that is outside the scope of this comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your current html and body tags with following:

```
html {
display: table;
margin: auto;
}

 body {
 font: 12px/20px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 20px;  
 color: rgb(102, 101, 101);
 position: relative;
 width: 1200px;
 background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 }
```

`
Let me know if it work for you!

Comment: Hey Hikeo Jaueem! You are genious... Thank you so much for your help....It is working properly ...I think the code in Html tag worked on this .... Great Help :)

Comment: You are most welcome! I hope now you will accept my answer :)